# What is a good name for class which creates factories? (FooFactoryFactory sounds silly imo)

Tags: java, design-patterns, oop, naming-conventions

I don't remember exactly is it a common pattern but I have a class (Factory Method pattern) which has method for creating other classes (Abstract Factory pattern) depending on enum parameter:

```
public class FooFactoryFactory {
   public FooFactory createFactory (FooFactoryType type) {
      switch (type) {
         case AFoo:
            return new AFooFactory ();
            break;
         case BFoo:
            return new BFooFactory ();
            break;
         default:
            throw new RuntimeException ("...");
      }  
   }
}

public interface FooFactory {
   Foo createFoo ();
   FooItem createFooItem ();
}
```

FooFactory has several implementations as well as Foo interface and FooItem interface (common Abstract Factory pattern).

So, how to rename FooFactoryFactory?

Maybe, FooFactoryCreator? (Think of this name during writing this question). IMHO it's nice, how do you think?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- `FooFactoryCreator`
- `FooFactoryProvider`

But you might want to rename your factories to, say, builders. Take a look at `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory`, which procudes `DocumentBuilder` instances, which in turn produce `Document`s

Looking into the `DocumentBuilderFactory` example, another option arises:

- have an abstract `FooFactory`
- make a `static newInstance()` method there (with parameters)
- let `newInstance()` return the appropriate implementation of `FooFactory`

Comment: Agreeable solution, only comment is a word of caution that only in rare instances is a "factory of factories" a truly necessary design. It sounds convoluted, and I'd be surprised if there weren't a more elegant pattern to apply to whatever the problem is. Case-in-point, DocumentBuilderFactory is so often misused (especially from a thread safety perspective), that I would immediately question any code of mine that could be compared to it.

Comment: To me, Factories create look-a-like objects while Builders allow much more control over customization of the object being built before building it. For example, DocumentBuilder allows you to set number of properties about the document before building it while DocumentBuilderFactory creates a Factory implementation that can be used to create DocumentBuilder (with little to no customization).

Answer (score 4):

In [*Creating and Destroying Java Objects: Part 1*](http://www.drdobbs.com/java/208403883), the author suggests, "One advantage of static factory methods is that, unlike constructors, they have names." –[*Joshua Bloch*](http://www.drdobbs.com/java/208403883). You may get some ideas from the article.

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer by Bozho is pretty good, I'd really consider `FooFactoryFactory` even if it may sound silly. It conveys the intent like nothing else.

Alternative names are `FooMetaFactory` and `FooPreFactory`.

A possible different naming convention is `FooParent` and `FooGrandParent`.